# getting data from 3 tables via a recurring id

Tags: sql, mysql, database, join, relational-database

I have a database with 3 tables in this structure,

```
    CREATE TABLE `mailers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mailer_title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `mailer_header` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `mailer_type` enum('single','multi') NOT NULL,
  `introduction` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('live','dead','draft') NOT NULL,
  `flag` enum('sent','unsent') NOT NULL,
  `date_mailer_created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_mailer_updated` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=48 ;

CREATE TABLE `mailer_content` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `headline` varchar(320) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `mailer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position` enum('left','right','centre') DEFAULT NULL,
  `tab_1_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tab_1_link` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tab_2_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tab_2_link` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tab_3_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tab_3_link` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tab_4_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tab_4_link` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `mailer_id` (`mailer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=54 ;

CREATE TABLE `mailer_images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `mailer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=92 ;

ALTER TABLE `mailer_content`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `mailer_content_ibfk_1` 
     FOREIGN KEY (`mailer_id`) 
     REFERENCES `mailers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

How would I get all the data from all columns where the id and the mailer table is 47? I currently have this sql, I currently have this sql, but it is not returning the correct data,

```
   SELECT *
     FROM `mailers` 
LEFT JOIN `mailer_content` ON `mailers`.`id` = `mailer_content`.`mailer_id` 
LEFT JOIN `mailer_images` ON `mailer_content`.`id` = `mailer_images`.`content_id`
    WHERE `mailers`.`id` = 47
```

Comment: You're going to have to explain why the data returned from your query isn't correct.

Comment: Basically I am expecting 3 rows to be returned however it returning 6, but the 6 rows are the 3 I expect repeated. Using DISTINCT does nothing either

Comment: are you sure your data is correct, there is no duplicates in mailers?

Comment: the data is correct, there is defiantly no duplicates in mailers

Comment: can you publish the sample data as insert commands (in phpmyadmin, do an export) so i can try it locally.

Comment: @pixeline I have sorted it now, I have spilt the sql into two queries and run it through a foreach now. Many thanks for your help though!!I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You omitted a join condition on mailer_images:

```
SELECT *
     FROM `mailers` 
LEFT JOIN `mailer_content` ON `mailers`.`id` = `mailer_content`.`mailer_id` 
LEFT JOIN `mailer_images` ON `mailer_content`.`id` = `mailer_images`.`content_id`
                         AND `mailers`.`id` = `mailer_images`.`mailer_id` 
    WHERE `mailers`.`id` = 47
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT *
     FROM `mailers` 
LEFT JOIN `mailer_content` ON `mailers`.`id` = `mailer_content`.`mailer_id` 
LEFT JOIN `mailer_images` ON `mailer_images`.`mailer_id` = `mailer`.`id` 
    WHERE `mailers`.`id` = 47
```

Comment: that is returning 4 rows, but it just 2 rows duplicated